# Firebase Cloud Functions: Promise not Executing

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm having some trouble with promises in firebase cloud functions.
What I'm trying to do is take a document, extract the text from and search through that text for some search terms.

The issue I'm having is with promises.

EDIT:
I have attached the current code that I am working with, I have moved away from using sub functions to break up the code and this is all in one big block now.

This should help with debugging.

It is currently getting stuck when trying to retrieve the search patterns on line 93. This is stopping the code after this point from executing, however I do not know why this firestore query is not working.

I have added the fix proposed by @augustzf.

```
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
import path = require('path');
import suffixArray from './suffixArray';

interface suffix {
  index: number;
  rank: Array<any>;
}

interface Location {
  lid: string;
  location_name: string;
  location_type: string;
  sentimental_value: number;
}

interface Context {
  lid: string;
  context_string: string;
  fid: string;
}

export const processFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async file => {
  const fileBucket = file.bucket;
  const filePath = file.name;

  console.log(`File path ${filePath}`);

  const serviceAccount = require(__dirname + '/../config/serviceAccount.json');

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'someDB'
  });

  const firestore = admin.firestore();
  const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
  firestore.settings(settings);

  const fileDet = path.basename(filePath);
  const fileNameSplit = fileDet.split('.');
  const fileExt = fileNameSplit.pop();
  const fileName = fileNameSplit.join('.');
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
  const fileRef = bucket.file(filePath);
  const searchTerms = file.metadata.searchTerms.split(', ');
  let _path = '';
  console.log('Getting Download URL');
  try {
    _path = `/tmp/${fileName}.${fileExt}`;
    console.log(`Downloading to: ${_path}`);
    await fileRef.download({ destination: _path });
    console.log('File Saved');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  console.log(`Getting Details: ${_path}`);
  let text: string = '';

  switch (fileExt) {
    case 'docx':
    case 'doc':
      const WordExtractor = require('word-extractor');
      const extractor = new WordExtractor();
      const extracted = await extractor.extract(_path);
      text = extracted.getBody();
      break;
    case 'pdf':
      break;
    case 'txt':
      const textract = require('textract');
      textract.fromFileWithPath(_path, function(extractedError, string) {
        if (extractedError) {
          console.error(extractedError);
        }
        if (string !== null) {
          text = string;
        }
      });
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Unsupported File Type');
      return null;
  }
  console.log(`Processing: ${fileName}`);
  console.log('Creating Suffix Array');
  const suffix_array = suffixArray(text);
  console.log(`Suffix Array Created: ${suffix_array}`);
  console.log('Getting Search Patterns');
  let searchPatterns;
  try {
    searchPatterns = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('FYP_LOCATIONS')
      .get();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    console.log(`Search Patterns Received: ${searchPatterns}`);
    const contexts: Array<Context> = [];
    console.log('Creating Contexts');
    for (const searchPattern of searchPatterns.docs) {
      const patternDoc = searchPattern.data();
      const pattern: string = patternDoc.location_name.toLowerCase();
      console.log(pattern);
      console.log(`Beginning search for: ${pattern}`);
      let start = 0;
      let end = suffix_array.length;
      const matchedIndexes: Array<number> = [];

      while (start < end) {
        const mid: number = (end - 1) / 2;
        const index: number = suffix_array[mid];
        const finalIndex: number = index + pattern.length;
        if (finalIndex <= text.length) {
          const substring: string = text.substring(index, finalIndex);
          const match: number = pattern.localeCompare(substring);

          if (match === 0) {
            console.log(`Match Found at Index: ${index}`);
            matchedIndexes.push(index);
          } else if (match < 0) {
            end = mid;
          } else if (match > 0) {
            start = mid;
          }
          console.log(matchedIndexes);
        }
      }

      if (matchedIndexes.length === 0) {
        console.log(`No matches found for search term: ${pattern}`);
      }
      for (const index of matchedIndexes) {
        let left = index - 25;
        let right = index + patternDoc.location_name.length + 25;
        if (left < 0) {
          left = 0;
        }
        if (right > text.length) {
          right = text.length;
        }
        const context = text.substring(left, right);
        contexts.push({
          lid: patternDoc.lid,
          context_string: context,
          fid: fileName
        });
      }
    }
    for (const context of contexts) {
      admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('FYP_CONTEXTS')
        .add(context)
        .then(contextDoc => {
          console.log(`Context Added: ${contextDoc}`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  const data = {
    processed: 1
  };
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .doc('FYP_FILES/' + fileName)
    .update(data);
});
```

I've tried numerous approaches to try and solve this but haven't come up with anything, I have a feeling it's to do with the other existing promises in my code but I'm not sure.

Any help that you can offer would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

In general you should avoid using forEach with async methods. That's because forEach will start off every async call without keeping (and hence waiting for) the returned promise.

In your case this seems to be a problem in your method right here:

```
contexts.forEach(async (context: Context) => {
    try {
    const contextDoc = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('FYP_CONTEXTS')
        .add(context);
    console.log(`Context Added: ${contextDoc}`);
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Which would be better off like this:

```
for (const context of contexts) {
    try {
        const contextDoc = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('FYP_CONTEXTS')
            .add(context);
        console.log(`Context Added: ${contextDoc}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I will get that implemented and see if it makes a difference. :) Thank you!